# How to make collapsible sidebar sticky?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the sidebar in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/qn11L5bk/) sticky when scrolling, for both situations (when you are using a big display and the sidebar is visible, as well as on mobile devices when you toggle the menu manually). I have followed various similar answers on this site but I could not apply them to my particular situation. For example, the following did not help:

```
#sidebar.affix-top {
    position: static;
    margin-top:30px;
    width:228px;
}

#sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top:70px;
    width:228px;
}
```

Any ideas how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
#sidebar .nav {
    width: 95%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

works for me

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PrakharThakur/afrbbsh3/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it works only when the sidebar is not collapsed. If you toggle the sidebar from the toggle button, the links are not present. Also I see parts of the sidebar on the right side, which did not happen before